# Shopify : modify logo size

Tags: css, shopify

I try to modify the size of the logo in the navbar-logo, I use the "Shoppystore-Home1" template. I tried to modify the code but nothing happens.

```html
<div class="navbar-logo col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="">
          <div class="pull-left">
            {% if template == 'index' %}
            <h1 class="site-header-logo no-margin" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
              {% else %}
              <div class="site-header-logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
                {% endif %}

                {% if section.settings.logo and section.settings.logo_img %}
                <a href="/" itemprop="url" class="site-header-logo-image">
                  {% capture image_size %}{{ section.settings.logo_max_width }}x{% endcapture %}
                  <img src="{{ section.settings.logo | img_url: image_size }}"
                       srcset="{{ section.settings.logo | img_url: image_size }} 0.1x, {{ section.settings.logo | img_url: image_size, scale: 0.2 }} 0.2x"
                       alt="{{ section.settings.logo.alt | default: shop.name }}"
                       itemprop="logo">
                </a>
                {% else %}
                <a class="site-header-logo-link" href="/" itemprop="url">{{ section.settings.logo_text }}</a>
                {% endif %}
                {% if template == 'index' %}
                </h1>
              {% else %}
              </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: You have `image_size` which is equal to `section.settings.logo_max_width`. So you should have an option in the General settings panel where you can change the size of the logo.

Comment: Thanks, when I go to the customization interface I see it but if I change the value nothing change !

Comment: Can you highlight what part of the code you changed and show us the before and after? Many Shopify-fluent community members (hello!) may not be familiar with that theme and so don't know what you have modified.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me :) I have modified in my browser inspector the scale 2x to 1x and 1x to 0.5 and it worked but when I modified it in this code below it didnt work.`<img src="{{ section.settings.logo | img_url: image_size }}"
                       srcset="{{ section.settings.logo | img_url: image_size }} 0.1x, {{ section.settings.logo | img_url: image_size, scale: 0.2 }} 0.2x"
                       alt="{{ section.settings.logo.alt | default: shop.name }}"
                       itemprop="logo">`
You can see **0.1x** and **0.2x** that I modified